# Node JS Express Handling multiple requests

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, get

**What I Have:**
I have a nodejs express server get endpoint that in turn calls other APIs that are time consuming(say about 2 seconds). I have called this function with a callback such that the res.send is triggered as a part of the call back. The res.send object packs an object that will be created after the results from these time consuming API calls is performed. So my res.send can only be sent when I have the entire information from the API call.

Some representative code.

```
someFunctionCall(params, callback)
{
  // do some asyncronous requests.
  Promise.all([requestAsync1(params),requestAsync2(params)]).then
  {
     // do some operations
     callback(response) // callback given with some data from the promise
  }

}
app.get('/',function(req, res){
 someFunctionCall(params, function(err, data){
    res.send(JSON.stringify(data))
   }
}
```

**What I want**
I want my server to be able to handle other parallel incoming get requests without being blocked due to the REST api calls in the other function. But the problem is that the callback will only be issued when the promises are fulfilled,each of those operations are async, but my thread will wait till the execution of all of them. And Node does not accept the next get request without executing the res.send or the res.end of the previous request. This becomes an issues when I have multiple requests coming in, each one is executed one after another.

Note: I do not want to go with the cluster method, I just want to know if it is possible to this without it.

Comment: If you're using all async I/O in your time consuming operation (which you should be), then your understanding of how node.js works is not correct.  Node.js should be able to process lots of other requests while you are waiting for the time consuming API.  Promises and asynchronous operations do not block node.js from processing other requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not telling that promises block, all I am telling is that the callback only happens after the resolution of all the promises, which technically makes it a blocking call doesnt it? No?

Comment: No.  That's not blocking.  Other events can run just fine while during that time.  That's how async operations work in node.js.  Other things run just fine while node.js is waiting for that callback to get called.  It works exactly the same as `setTimeout(callback, t)`.  Other things run just fine in node.js while waiting for that callback.

Comment: FYI, the Javascript syntax you show for your `.then()` handler is not correct at all.  If should be `Promise.all([requestAsync1(params),requestAsync2(params)]).then(function(response) {callback(response)});`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are apparently misunderstanding how node.js, asynchronous operations and promises work.  Assuming your long running asynchronous operations are all properly written with asynchronous I/O, then neither your `requestAsync1(params)` or `requestAsync2(params)` calls are blocking.  That means that while you are waiting for `Promise.all()` to call its `.then()` handler to signify that both of those asynchronous operations are complete, node.js is perfectly free to run any other events or incoming requests.  Promises themselves do not block, so the node.js event system is free to process other events.  So, you either don't have a blocking problem at all or if you actually do, it is not caused by what you asked about here.

To see if your code is actually blocking or not, you can temporarily add a simple timer that outputs to the console like this:

```
let startTime;
setInterval(function() {
    if (!startTime) {
        startTime = Date.now();
    }
    console.log((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
}, 100)
```

This will output a simple relative timestamp every 100ms when the event loop is not blocked.  You would obviously not leave this in your code for production code, but it can be useful to show you when/if your event loop is blocked.

---

I do see an odd syntax issue in the code you included in your question.  This code:

```
someFunctionCall(params, callback)
{
  // do some asyncronous requests.
  Promise.all([requestAsync1(params),requestAsync2(params)]).then
  {
     // do some operations
     callback(response) // callback given with some data from the promise
  }

}
```

should be  expressed like this:

```
someFunctionCall(params, callback)
{
  // do some asyncronous requests.
  Promise.all([requestAsync1(params),requestAsync2(params)]).then(function(response)
  {
     // do some operations
     callback(response) // callback given with some data from the promise
  }

});
```

But, an even better design would be to just return the promise and not switch back to a plain callback.  Besides allowing the caller to use the more flexible promises scheme, you are also "eating" errors that may occur in either or your async operations.  It's suggest this:

```
someFunctionCall(params) {
  // do some asyncronous requests.
    return Promise.all([requestAsync1(params),requestAsync2(params)]).then(function(results) {
        // further processing of results
        // return final resolved value of the promise
        return someValue;
    });
}
```

Then, then caller would use this like:

```
someFunctionCall(params).then(function(result) {
    // process final result here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: The suggestion to check for any synchronous op in the event loop was a good one, I indeed did have a synchronous op that missed my notice the first time i went through the code. Thank you so much for the help. Regarding the second concern that you raised with the syntax of the then() yes I had used the correct syntax, but made an error when writing out a analogous code to the same.

Comment: Will it not block the subsequent request if you use await on a promise object @Kakarot

Comment: @SasiKumar - I don't know exactly what code you're asking about.  `await` suspends execution of the current function until the promise you're awaiting completes, but other things in the event loop can still run just fine during the `await`.