# Socket.io socket picks up packet slowly

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use socket.io on a node server and while testing it I noticed quite some lag in the socket communication, when I was connected with 2 accounts, so I enabled debugging and found out that after the parser decodes the packet the socket takes a lot of time to pick it up, like so:
[example logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4er1e.png)

in this case, its "only" 1 sec but often can be more. It's happening on all types of messages (connection to a namespace for example).
Server uses express, cors, body-parser, passport.
Anyone familiar with this issue?

Edit:
Even if I do the most simple thing, the got packet takes a lot of time.
[simple test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8TUp.png)

Comment: Is your server busy doing something else during that time?

Comment: nop, already tore it down all the way to a simple on message -> broadcast boilerplate, but the issue persists.

Comment: Any happening shortly beforehand that could cause the garbage collector to have a lot of work to do?  May need to do some profiling to find out where the CPU cycles are going.

Comment: Also, is this a single CPU computer?  Anything else on the computer using the CPU?  Can you tell if the CPU is at 100% or at 0% to figure out if the CPU is busy or if the delay is caused by something else.

Comment: got a single i5, checked it out, no excess CPU or memory usage

Comment: Look at the `setInterval()` snippet of code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172684/node-js-express-handling-multiple-requests/47184016#47184016) and you can try that out to see if your process is getting blocked from processing events or if the cause is something else.  You should see a timestamp every 100ms if the event loop is not being blocked by anything.

Comment: You're on to something. If I start the timer right at the start the lagging behavior stops! If I start it for example when a certain user logs in, the login process lags but once the timer starts the messaging works fine. Like the process hibernates until it doesn't do something. Can node do that?

Comment: I've never heard of node doing that on its own.

Comment: This seems to be this problem here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3100. I have the same problem and it is annoying me atm :|

Comment: thanks a lot, Matthias, changing the wsEngine does the trick, at least for temporarily!