# Handle Express requests one at a time

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

In Express, is it possible to handle requests to a single route *one at a time*? I have a "checkout queue," and each time a checkout is created, stock is decreased. However, a simultaneous `POST` request to create a checkout checks the stock *before* stock is decreased in the first request, which causes overselling. *Note: the request only takes about 300 ms, so using Bull or any other queueing technique seems a bit over-the-top.* Is there any way I can configure a route to accept requests one-at-a-time?

I am using Firestore as the datastore.

Comment: Which database/store do you use? It should be definitely handled there not on application level.

Comment: @Animir I use Firestore, but updating the database and fetching documents is also, unfortunately, asynchronous.

Comment: Looks like, you should use [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions)

Comment: @Animir I swear, every once in a while somebody on this site gives an answer worth a damn and it makes me so happy. Thanks a million :)

Comment: @BenBotvinick Can you include a code solution to your problem so that we can learn what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use blocking operations on store level like [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) for Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below npm module this you can use as a middleware

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Comment: This does not answer the question. My goal is not to restrict incoming requests from 1 IP, it’s to handle each request from all clients one at a time.

Comment: @BenBotvinick You could use [RateLimiterQueue](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/RateLimiterQueue) for that, but it is better to make atomic updated on store level if possible.

Answer (score -2):

Node.js by its nature, is a single-threaded application so it cannot execute multiple requests at once. What happens internally in its event loop,it can add callback into an event queue.

[image]

You can use [async/await](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-express/) paradigm to handle multiple requests.

Comment: Yes. But asynchronous requests are processed simultaneously outside of that event loop.

Comment: Node is single threaded. The requests are queued asynchronously and event loop handles the request one by one. You are confusing asynchronous behaviour with non-blocking IO behaviour

Comment: Ok, how do I apply this to my question?

Comment: Check this answer to gain context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172684/node-js-express-handling-multiple-requests

Comment: Two async requests can create race conditions on store level.